# S3 Object that only some of my users can access

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want some guidance as to how to go about this:

I want to have some objects in my S3 bucket by accessible only be a few users (users from my web app). I looked through the AWS docs and it seems as though I need to give each of my users AWS access keys(?).

Obviously I don't want to do this, so is there any way in my app to lock out some users and let other in? I'm using Node.JS and MySQL (to store my users) if that makes a difference.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simple description of the S3 access / permission scheme is...Access to S3, like most other AWS resources is based on IAM-centric access controls.  So, you can either grant access to your S3 buckets by either granting users access to it (setting it on S3) or granting S3 access to a user (setting it in IAM as a policy).  So, whatever or whomever is accessing S3 must be authenticated to AWS.  Again, that is a very high-level description and meant to simply point out that access is based on user/role authentication.

Now, assuming your web-app is running on AWS (EC2?), than your EC2 instance has been (hopefully) assigned an IAM role.  Once that IAM Role has been assigned the permissions to do so, the application running on the EC2 instance can now access any AWS resource via that Role.

But, you don't want ALL of your webapp users to access S3, so my two thoughts are:

1) Check the users credentials within your app (assuming the user needs to authenticate somehow with your application) and make the determination of whether or not to call S3 based on the users credentials.  You would then use the IAM Role assigned to the EC2 instance (an EC2 instance can only have 1 IAM Role assigned to it) and access S3 or not.

This second idea is a pretty bad one and smells bad to me.  I'm pointing it out merely as a possibility and to highlight how the use of IAM Users / Roles works.

2) This suggestion would not utilize the IAM Role assigned to the EC2 instance, though I would always advocate for assigning a Role to the instance, you can always lock down that role and deny access to all AWS resources, but you can't add a role to the instance after launched.

Have two IAM Users (S3Granted and S3Denied, each of which obviously have appropriate policies for accessing S3).  Each user of your webapp (e.g. Hillary Clinton, Donald Trump, Bernie Sanders and Ted Cruz) would then each map to one of the two IAM Users based on whether or not they should have access to S3.  This would be a field in your MySQL database.  You wouldn't bother checking the credentials up-front (because then you would just be performing Option #1 and would proceed with the S3 call regardless of the user and S3 will either grant or deny access based on the IAM User account your webapp user is associated with.  You technically wouldn't need the S3Denied User (you could just have no user), but I figured it would be cleaner to specify the IAM User.

e.g.:

```
WebAppUser/Bernie Sanders --> IAMUser/S3Granted
WebAppUser/Hillary Clinton --> IAMUser/S3Denied
WebAppUser/Ted Cruz --> IAMUser/S3Granted
WebAppUser/Donald Trump --> IAMUser/S3Denied
```

For Option #2, you would then need to store the Access keys for both IAM Users m(S3Granted and S3Denied) somewhere so that you could properly authenticate.

Also, you would need to do a bit of exception handling so that you could properly notify your users that they have been denied access.

Overall, #2 is just a bad idea.  It would be much cleaner if you simply had a field in your MySQL database that specified whether or not they can access S3 and either make the S3 call via the IAM Role or refuse to do so within your webapp.  Don't leave it to S3 to grant or deny access.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response! Assuming I go with option 1, would I make all of the S3 objects private, and then fetch them through the AWS API for an authenticated user? If so, how is the best way (performance wise that you know of) to do this? I am going to use videos heavily in my app, so speed is important (Or am I correct in thinking that the performance of fetching a private object from the AWS API is the same, or better, than from a public S3 URL). Thanks again!

Comment: Well, that's a bit more difficult to answer and should probably be a different and more well-thought-out question for someone on SO to answer.  I would think apples-to-apples, the public URL would be faster because via the API, it needs to download to the server (which is INCREDIBLY fast) and then you serve it up via standard HTTP (or whatever protocol you're using) vs. simply serving it up via HTTP (or whatever protocol you're using) straight from S3.  However, there might be manipulation you can do server side (e.g. compression) that would make the users download much smaller / faster.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't mean to go out of scope of this question :) Thanks for your help! That is kind of what I figured I would have to do. But now I have a path forward!